# How to become a Sewage Mutant on Futurama

Tags: futurama, retcon, mutant

In the [first second season episode of futurama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Second_That_Emotion_%28Futurama%29) Fry gets cut down from a rope and falls into the sewage (whcih you hear him spit and cough out)

In a [more recent episode of futurama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mutants_Are_Revolting) it is told of the "Land Titanic" that sunk and all who were on it became a mutant, and if one drank the mutant sewage, you would become one too (as fry did).

How was this retconned in?  Is it ever explained why Fry did not become a mutant in that first episode?

Comment: Fry didn't become a sewer mutant in The Mutants are Revolting.  He was swallowed by Mr. Astor. He only appeared to have mutated.

Comment: @Legion600 true, but that is because Mr Astor protected Fry from the sewage, otherwise it is stated that one would become a mutant from drinking it.

Comment: In the Mutants are Revolting at the 4m30s mark a narrator notes that it took generations for the mutants to mutate into what they are. Also, Leela tells Fry in a fit of pique that if he jumps into the sludge he will be mutated.  There's no evidence it would actually happen.  It's probably just a sub-urban legend.

Comment: @TheDoctor just touching it is enough to be mutated. Drinking is optional. And not encouraged.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The scene you describe features Fry, off camera, falling into the sewer. However, not all sewer water is mutegenic ooze. Only the sludge in the town will instantly turn you into a mutant if you aren't one already. Regular sewer water isn't enough. And Fry was simply falling into the plain-old sewer, where normal waste-water has yet to become mutant-producing.

Initially I was going to say it was only the glowing ooze, but upon re-watching all the related scenes it seems that glowing isn't the required attribute. The glow was a temporary condition that eventually went away, long before the first attempts at changing anyone into a mutant. It was introduced by Bender when he dumped tons of radioactive waste into the sewer.

For some more evidence, please watch [Teenage Mutant Leela's Hurdles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teenage_Mutant_Leela%27s_Hurdles). There is a boat race there which almost certainly got sewer water on Fry. If all of the water was mutegenic, he would have been mutated then.

Legion600 brings up another good point. We've never actually seen anyone mutate. Although Leela did use her own lack of changes as evidence to come to realize her own mutant status.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right in regards to seeing 'anyone' mutate. There are however non-human creatures that mutate instantaneously due to exposure.

Comment: @user13095 Correct. There is that horrific pig-fish thing.